# Invariant Violation: A <Router> may have only one child element when testing (Jest + Enzyme)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am starting to test a React + Redux + React-router application and I have been struggling with some basic tests.

This is my component (company-view.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {withCookies} from 'react-cookie';
import CompanyShow from '../components/company-show';

const styles = {
  pageContainer: {
    padding: '0px 25px'
  }
}

class CompanyView extends Component {

  render() {
    if (this.props.cookies.get('user').position !== 'Gerente Innovación') {
       return <Redirect to='/forbidden'/>;
     }
    return (
      <div style={styles.pageContainer}>
        <h3>Mi Empresa</h3>
        <CompanyShow />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withCookies(CompanyView);
```

This is my test file (company-view.test.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CompanyView from '../company-view';
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { MemoryRouter} from 'react-router';

it('should redirect to forbidden if not \'Gerente de Innovación\'', () => {
  let cookies = new Cookies()
  cookies.set('user', {position: 'Not \'Gerente de Innovación\''}, { path: '/' });

  const context = {
    cookies: cookies
  }

  const wrapper = mount( <MemoryRouter><CompanyView /> </MemoryRouter>, {context});
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
```

The problem is that this tests fails with the following error:

Invariant Violation: A  may have only one child element

It also says:

console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9747
      The above error occurred in the  component:
          in Router (created by MemoryRouter)
          in MemoryRouter (created by WrapperComponent)
          in WrapperComponent

```
  Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

I am using react 16.0.0, react-dom 16.0.0, react-router 4.2.0 and react-router-dom 4.2.2

I made the app using create-react-app and as the title says I am using Jest + Enzyme to make the tests.

Thanks in advance, if you need any other information please let me know!

Comment: What happens if you export the `CompanyView` class without the `withCookie` for testing?

Comment: I recommend testing your component free from its dependencies like router and cookies. The component doesn't know where its `cookies` prop comes from, it just expects it to have a certain shape (which you can provide).

If you just want a snapshot test, I would also reach for `shallow` over `mount`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll investigate how to do what @MikeSchutte said